# UIView animation warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimation-curve

I am using following code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.05
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                                  //Code

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

I am getting the following warning

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIViewAnimationCurve' to different enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions')
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be using `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` instead.

`UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn` is part of a different enum used in other methods.